# Solving a PDE involving cylindrical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, cylindrical-coordinates

[image]

For this question I'm struggling to gather exactly what PDE's I should be solving here. I'm also struggling to understand what the boundary conditions would look like for such a question, which is the reason why I don't know how to start. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I'm struggling to gather exactly what PDE's I should be solving here.
```

You only need to express the [Laplacian in cylindrical polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Coordinate_expressions) $(\sigma, \phi)$ [what a strange notation!] to have:

$$\rho \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}  = G  + \mu \left[ \frac{1}{\sigma} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \left( \sigma \frac{\partial w}{\partial \sigma}\right) + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \phi^2}   \right] $$

where we have used the fact that the flow is fully developed and therefore does not depend on $z$ (that is, $w = w(\sigma, \phi)$).

```
I'm also struggling to understand what the boundary conditions would look like for such a question
```

To solve for the axial velocity you must impose a no-slip condition at the walls, meaning that $w = 0$ at $\sigma = a$, $-\beta < \phi < \beta$ and at $\phi = \pm \beta$, $\sigma < a$. As for the center of the cylinder $\sigma = 0$, you will have to get rid of the singular part of the solution so as to keep the velocity bounded at all times.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should notice that the problem is asking for the **steady** solution of the problem so you might as well get rid of the  $\partial_t$ term.